# Python: How to to adjust the size of the window and the size of the buffer independently?

Tags: python, size, buffer

I have to pack and run the .py file with the PyInstaller. Here, I want to reduce the size of the window and leave the buffer size of the window as it is. In other words, I want to reduce the size of the window while leaving the vertical scroll bar. I would sincerely appreciate it if you could tell me the solution.

What I tried::

```
os.system("mode con: cols=50 lines=10")
subprocess.call('C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=50;$B.height=900;$W.buffersize=$B;}"', shell=True)
```